# WCF client not mapping and returning null objects

Tags: c#, wcf

I've setup a Service Reference (WCF Client) to call a Java Web Service from a Console Application I've setup for testing. It is using HTTPS. I have Fiddler setup and can see the proper values being sent and returned from the service (in Fiddler). But no matter what method I call, the returned values, regardless if it is a String or an object, comes back as Null.

I'm not sure if the proxy client mapping isn't working or if I need to change a configure value in app.config.

app.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
    </startup>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <customBinding>
                <binding name="ResultsSOAP12Binding">
                    <textMessageEncoding messageVersion="Soap12" />
                </binding>
                <binding name="ResultsSOAP12Binding1">
                    <textMessageEncoding messageVersion="Soap12" />
                    <httpsTransport />
                </binding>
                <binding name="ResultsSOAP12Binding2">
                    <textMessageEncoding messageVersion="Soap12" />
                </binding>
            </customBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="https://services.acme.com/results"
                binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="ResultsSOAP12Binding1"
                contract="ResultsServiceReference.Result
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Code:

```
static void CallResults()
        {
            var resultsRequest = new ResultsServiceReference.ResultsRequest();

            var client = new ResultsServiceReference.ResultsPortTypeClient("ResultsSOAP12BindingQSPort");

            Console.WriteLine("Call Results Service");

            ResultsServiceReference.ResultsBatch result = client.latestResults(resultsRequest);

            Console.WriteLine(result.Status);

        Console.ReadLine();

        }
```

In this code the variable **result** is null, even though when you look in Fiddler you can see the XML. No error is displayed until you try to use result.

BTW, I tried setting a breakpoint inside the latestResults method in the proxy class reference.cs, but the debugger doesn't reach it.

Comment: Sounds like a de-serialization issue, has the remote schema changed and invalidated your `ResultsBatch` proxy class?

Comment: This is a new setup. I agree it sounds like a deserialization issue. Since the breakpoint in the proxy class isn't reached, what the best way to troubleshoot?

Comment: do you mean you can see the correct response using fiddler?

Comment: The proxy is generated from the WSDL file. If the WSDL is not correct, this is the behavior to be expected. Have you validated your WSDL?

Comment: Yes, I can see the proper response in Fiddler. Yes the WSDL is valid and has been in use with non-WCF consumers for a few years.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to configure and enable WCF diagnostic event tracing and message logging, then rerun the test transaction and review the service trace log file. The following link demonstrates how to enable tracing and message logging.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751526.aspx

In our experience, service discrepancies which otherwise show no obvious error, often show up in the service trace file.

Note: The breakpoint inside the proxy class reference.cs may not be reached because the following attribute has been set:

```
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
```

Answer (score 1):

Most probably the WSDL has a mistake and the schema inside it does not match the actual response XML. You can publish the WSDL (and any referenced XSD) here together with the SOAP response (or mail them to me so I will try to look). Or you can set up a WCF service stub from the exact same WSDL (or from the client contract you already generated) and compare the response WCF sends to the one the actual service sends.
You want to look for differences in XML namespaces (and understand delicate parts like if this is default namespace or prefixed one) and in the name of the first element under the body.